# Find relative extrema of $(x-2)^{\frac{2}{3}}+1$ using second derivative test

Tags: calculus

The relative extrema of this function can be determine by using first derivative but I'm curious on how to determine its relative extrema if we use second derivative test.
The critical value is $x=2$. 
The second derivative is $\frac{-2}{9x-18\sqrt[3]{x-2}}$. 
When I solved for the f''(c), the answer was undefined:
$$f''(2) = \frac{-2}{9(2)-18\sqrt[3]{(2)-2}}$$
$$f''(2) = \frac{-2}{0}$$
$$f''(2)\;is\;undefined$$
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$f'(x)=\frac{2}{3}(x-2)^{-1/3}>0$$